Make My Own Docked Cell Save Button That Turn Red if the Notebook Has Any New Edits
The following code generates a docked cell button that when clicked will open up the save dialog. Freel free to run the code.
buttonsave = Button[Style["Save"], FrontEndTokenExecute["Save"]];
CreateWindow[
  DockedCells -> Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[buttonsave]], "DockedCell"]];

I would like the button label "Save" to turn red if there are any new edits in the notebook.  This will be a nice visual indicator to remind me that I need to click the Save button or I will lose any new edits I have made if I accidently close the notebook or Mathematica freezes up.
I'm not sure how to go about this.  Any ideas?
Edit 1:  I think I've made some progress.  The following code outputs information including the cell change times of very cell in the notebook.
NotebookRead[Cells[SelectedNotebook[]]]

It seems that I need to somehow check this after every key stroke to see if there are any changes in CellChangeTime.  If there are I want it to change the word "Save" in the button to red.  Still not sure how to do this.

As shown in the answer for Knowing when a notebook has changed programmatically, you can get the information about the state of the notebook via NotebookInformation. However, it seems that getting this value dynamically does not really work as expected*.
Thanks to @ihojnicki, there seems to be an undocumented feature CurrentValue["NotebookModified"], which does indeed react to any changed in the document:
nb = InputNotebook[];

SetOptions[nb, DockedCells -> Cell[BoxData@
    ToBoxes@Button[Style["Save"], FrontEndTokenExecute["Save"]], 
    "DockedCell", Background -> Dynamic@If[CurrentValue[nb, "NotebookModified"], 
    LightRed, LightGray]]]



* To see the problems with dynamic NotebookInformation, try this:
nb = InputNotebook[];

SetOptions[nb, DockedCells -> 
  Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@Button[Style["Save"], FrontEndTokenExecute["Save"]], 
   "DockedCell", Background -> Dynamic@If["ModifiedInMemory" /.
     NotebookInformation@nb, LightRed, LightGray]]]

The color will not change immediately after a change in the notebook, but you have to either hover over the button or resize the window ... This is because NotebookInformation calls the front-end to get its information, and it seems that it is not being reevaluated on changes.

You suggested listening to the events of keystrokes, which is possible using NotebookEventsAction, but you should avoid it, because it is an inefficient overkill for this situation:
SetOptions[nb, 
 DockedCells -> 
  Cell[BoxData@
    ToBoxes@Button[Style["Save"], 
     (FrontEndTokenExecute["Save"]; $notebookChanged = False)], "DockedCell", 
   Background -> Dynamic[If[$notebookChanged =!= False, LightRed, LightGray]]],
 NotebookEventActions -> {"KeyDown" :> ($notebookChanged = True), 
   PassEventsDown -> True}
 ]


I would avoid NotebookEventActions, since it is highly inefficient for this use.  You can use CurrentValue["NotebookModified"] instead.  Undocumented, but I doubt it will change drastically in the future.

@ihojnicki, thanks for sharing another undocumented feature!
